# Checking the presence of a number in a string on a single row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this **string** in my MySQL Database:
 **The string is on a single row**:
25 12 6 3 780

-I want to check if for example a variable **$data='6'**, is in the string above;
Return the value of the data if TRUE, and FALSE otherwise;

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%$data%'
```

doesn't work because it returns all the string...
Any ideas?

Comment: It returns all the string, isn't that what you want? or all strings?

Comment: @sagi I want to check if the value of $data is in the string, and return it if true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This will returns how many times the exact data exists in particular stings:*

#### Solution 1:

```
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS dataCount 
    FROM table_name t 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$data."',REPLACE(t.column_name,' ',',')) > 0";
```

#### php version(1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS dataCount FROM table_name t WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$data."',REPLACE(t.column_name,' ',',')) > 0");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$value=$data['dataCount'];
```

*This will returns all the strings where the exact data exists in:*

#### Solution 2:

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_name t 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$data."',REPLACE(t.column_name,' ',',')) > 0";
```

#### php version(2):

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name t WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$data."',REPLACE(t.column_name,' ',',')) > 0");
  $data=mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: @mitiksoft , the first  solution works just fine for my problem, it returns what is should, now I will see how to return the value in php to assign it to a variable, thanks for the help!

Comment: It will be great if you are stop using mysql_* functions, use mysqli_* instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if (exists (...))

```
 select if (exists (SELECT * 
           FROM table_name 
           WHERE column_name LIKE '%$data%'), 1,0) ;
```